# improving TikZ coordinate system/ voltage curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm somewhat new to TikZ (this is my second TikZ picture so far :)  )

It looks pretty much how I want it to look like, but I guess the code could be optimized. I have to draw quite a few similar voltage curves, so it would be nice if you could help me to optimize it!

Please note: The difference between the time tics and the visual appearance of the curve is on purpose!

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

% horizontal axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.5,0) node (xaxis) [anchor=north] {t};

% vertical axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2.5) node (yaxis) [anchor=east] {U};

% line
\draw[dotted] (1,0) coordinate (a) -- (1,1);
\draw[dotted]   (2,0) -- (2,2)
            (4,0) -- (4,2)
            (5,0) -- (5,1)
            (6,0) -- (6,1);

% labels time
    \draw   (0.5,1) node[anchor=north] {$t_0$}
    (1.5,1) node[anchor=north] {$t_r$}
    (3,1) node[anchor=north] {$t_1$}
    (4.5,1) node[anchor=north] {$t_f$}
    (5.5,1) node[anchor=north] {$t_2$};

%labels timestep
\draw   (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0}
    (1,0) node[anchor=north] {1}
    (2,0) node[anchor=north] {4}
    (4,0) node[anchor=north] {10}
    (5,0) node[anchor=north] {11}
    (6,0) node[anchor=north] {13};        

%labels voltage
\draw   (-0.5,1) node {$U_1$}
    (-0.5,2) node {$U_2$};

% Us
\draw[thick] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (2,2) -- (4,2) -- (5,1) -- (6,1);
%\draw[thick] (6,1) sin (7,0) cos (8,1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graphic]

Comment: Could you better explain what `similar voltage curves` means? Are all of them based on six coordinates? Are all labels always the same? ...

Comment: @Ignasi: No, they have different numbers of segments. But each segment has to be labled like here.

Comment: Part of the graphs are kind of like in this document: http://www.testforce.com/testforce_files/Seminars/SpirentAutomotiveSeminar2016/SpirentAutomotiveLV124-LV148V.pdf

Comment: Maybe it's possible to define the points and generate the labels and vertical lines out of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be following code helps. It reduces all voltage line drawing to one `foreach` loop where each element consists in four values `x coordinate/y coordinate/time label/segment label`. Initial point coordinates are *hidden* inside `initially` parameter.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% horizontal axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.5,0) node (xaxis) [anchor=north] {t};

% vertical axis
\draw[->] (0,0) node[below]{0} -- (0,2.5) node (yaxis) [anchor=east] {U};

\foreach \x/\y/\t/\l [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0), 
                       remember=\y as \lasty (initially 1)] in 
                       {1/1/1/$t_0$,2/2/4/$t_r$,4/2/10/$t_1$,5/1/11/$t_f$,6/1/13/$t_2$}{
% voltage line
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty)--(\x,\y);
% vertical reference
    \draw[dotted] (\x,\y)--(\x,0) node[below] {\t};
% time label
    \path (\lastx,1)--node[below] {\l} (\x,1);
}

\path (0,1) node[left] {$U_1$};
\path (0,2) node[left] {$U_2$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it. This makes it much easier :). Latex and TikZ are just amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what a voltage curve looks like in general but it seems that you need to specify some `(t,U)`-coordinates, labels for the `t`-axis and the subscripts for the regions. I'd use a `\foreach` loop and throw everything into a macro that accepts the initial voltage and a comma separated list of the "coordinates" for the voltage curve like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

    % \VoltageCurve[#1]{#2}
    %    #1 = optional initial voltage (default 1)
    %    #2 = comma separated list of t/U/t-label/t-subscript
    \newcommand\VoltageCurve[2][1]{%
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw  (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0};
          \def\Umax{#1}
          \foreach \t/\U/\tlab/\tsub [remember=\t as \tt (initially 0),
                                      remember=\U as \UU (initially #1)] in {#2} {
             \draw  (\t,0) node[anchor=north] {\tlab};
             \draw[dotted](\t,0)--(\t,\U);
             \draw[thick](\tt,\UU)--(\t,\U);
             \node[anchor=north] at ($ (\tt,1)!0.5!(\t,1) $) {$t_\tsub$};
             \ifnum\U>\Umax\xdef\Umax{\U}\fi% Umax = max{y}
          }
          % axes
          \draw[thin,->] (0,0) -- (\tt+0.5,0) node [anchor=north] {t};
          \draw[thin,->] (0,0) -- (0,\Umax+0.5) node[anchor=east] {U};
          % labels
          \node at (-0.5, #1) {$U_1$};
          \node at (-0.5, \Umax) {$U_2$};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \VoltageCurve{1/1/1/0, 2/2/4/r, 4/2/10/1, 5/1/11/f, 6/1/13/2}

    \VoltageCurve[2]{1/1/1/0, 2/2/4/r, 5/3/10/1, 7/1/11/f, 8/3/13/2, 9/1/16/z}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output of my MWE:

[image]

A few words of explanation:

- the (forward) slashes separate the variables in the `\foreach` loop
- the `\tt` and `\UU` variables "remember" the previous values of `\t` and `\U`, respectively
- `\Umax` remembers the maximum value of `\U` for drawing the `\U` axis
- the `\t` coordinates are assumed to be increasing
- the optional first argument gives the initial voltage (default 1)
- the first `\t`-label is assumed to be `0`
- to place the `t_<sub>` label I use `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to determine the point half-way  in between `\tt` and `t` using `($ (\tt,1)!0.5!(\t,1) $)`. It might be better to set the height of these labels to the initial voltage by replacing this with `($ (\tt,#1)!0.5!(\t,#1) $)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it. This makes it much easier :). Latex and TikZ are just amazing!

Comment: The separators in the `\foreach` are _(forward) slashes_, not backslashes.