# Is it possible for a TikZ `\foreach` loop list to be defined with a macro that takes argument(s)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

This question is similar to [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091/18401) but here I'd like the macro-defined list *to take an argument*.

For example, in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Macro without argument]
  \newcommand{\macrowithoutargument}{0,...,10}%
  \foreach \x in \macrowithoutargument {[\x]}
\item[Macro with argument]
  \newcommand{\macrowithargument}[1]{#1,...,10}%
%  \foreach \x in \macrowithargument{1} {[\x]}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

the `\foreach` loop with:

- macro-without-argument-defined list (`\macrowithoutargument)` works like a charm,
- macro-with-argument-defined list (`\macrowithargument{1}`) fails.

Please note that I'm stick with `TikZ`'s `\foreach` loops: the previous MWE is a minimization of a problem I encounter with `TikZ` picture where I'd like to draw just a part of a protactor, with the start and end angles given as arguments of a macro.

Hence my question: is it possible for the `TikZ`'s `\foreach` loop list to be defined with a macro that takes argument(s)?

Comment: Workaround: `\edef\tmp{\macrowithargument{1}}
  \foreach \x in \tmp {[\x]}`

Comment: I think a better solution is to put the whole for loop in a macro. `\foreach` is programmed to accept either a list, or a macro without arguments that produces a list.

Comment: Do you mean something like the `\VoltageCurve` command in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339611/improving-tikz-coordinate-system-voltage-curve/339625#339625 ?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, except I wanted the macro with parameter to be used as list, not to put the to put the whole for loop in a macro, as answered by David or suggested by Piet.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Write an answer with your "workaround"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Macro without argument]
  \newcommand{\macrowithoutargument}{0,...,10}%
  \foreach \x in \macrowithoutargument {[\x]}
\item[Macro with argument]
  \newcommand{\macrowithargument}[1]{\foreach \x in {#1,...,10}}%
  \macrowithargument{1} {[\x]}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is so easy when well written. I'll use my `\irange` and `\jrange` now